# php excluding piece of html code?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a custom CMS here entitled phpVMS, and I want to exclude a piece of code, a banner for a single page. phpVMS is steered using templates, for instance, the main template that codes the general layout for all pages is entitled layout.tpl. So, like I said, this displays whatever is in the template, on all of the pages. I have however created a special control panel, and therefore require to exclude the banner, because it slightly destroys the theme of it. Is there any PHP code that excludes a piece of code on a single site? I need to remove a single div...

```
<div id="slideshow"></div>
```

...on a single page.

Basically, I could create a new template but this is a very long winded and unefficient way within this CMS, and the final result isn't that great - because I can't reinclude the mainbox div which is the box defining the content on the centre white bit of the theme - it's already in the layout.tpl.

I hope you can somehow help me, hope I've included enough information there.

Thanks.

Comment: not an answer per se, but does adding the js (assuming you are using jquery) $("#slideshow").hide() ; fix the issue while you are looking for  a perm. solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you're asking in PHP, but you might be able to do this on the client-side, by either hiding the div (CSS `display:none`) or by removing it with JavaScript. You might be able to do something like:

```
<?php
    include("layout.tpi");

    if (condition)
    {
        // Javascript:
        echo "<script>document.getElementById('slideshow').style.display = 'none';</script>";

        // OR jQuery:
        echo "<script>$('#slideshow').hide();</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked without the include, as the template is already included :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a variable to determine you don't want to include the div, you could do this:

```
<?php if ($include) { ?>
    <div id="slideshow"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
    if (!$include)
        echo "<!--";
?>
<div id="slideshow"></div>
<?php 
    if (!$include)
        echo "-->";
?>
```

EDIT: Obviously, there is no good reason to use the second method. The second method will only comment out the HTML so it will still show up in the source.

Comment: The template layout.tpl defines all of the pages content, where div slideshow is now. I've added the above code to profile_main.tpl at the top of it, and it doesn't work. I guess you've mentioned a variable, how would I make one? Sorry, still learning PHP...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but seems simple

```
<?
$template = true;
if($template) {
?>
<div id="slideshow"></div>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the template, you could have some code that reads:

```
if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == /*control panel file*/) {
     //exclude
}else{
     //include
}
```